# Confirm dialog doesn't work after return false

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I have a basic javascript confirm dialog to confirm whether or not a user wants to proceed with an action.  The dialog works correctly if the user simply clicks OK or Cancel.  However, if the user clicks Cancel, then re-triggers the dialog, then clicks OK the form is not submitted.

I've included my code below, is there a better way to handle this when what I'm doing here?

```
$("#myButton").click(function (event) {
    var result = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that I've also tried `event.preventDefault` in place of `return false` and I see the same result.

Comment: Isn't some code missing? The form etc? Because, I can't see the place where you do something with "result", except for some useless if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I might get what you're trying to achieve.
Just bind the event to your form submit handler instead of the button click. This will also trigger, if the user is sending the form using his keyboard etc.

```
<form id="wohoo" action="/somewhere">
    <input />
    <input type="submit" value="send me"/>
</form>​

$("#wohoo").submit(function () {
    var result = confirm("Are you sure?");

    return result;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tSbJ/

Comment: The issue actually turned out to be that my template engine (ASPX) was injecting an extra click handler elsewhere.  However, the solution above works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to confirm form submition try this instead

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    return confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```